# Is there any way to replace all vowels with an underscore "_" before a specific symbol?

Tags: regex, replace

For example, I have the following text -

```
scrmbl~sparkling|sparkling#
scrmbl~portable|portable#
scrmbl~serious|serious#
scrmbl~headphone|headphone#
```

I wish to replace all the vowels before the `|` symbol with an underscore, so, it will look like this -

```
scrmbl~sp_rkl_ng|sparkling#
scrmbl~p_rt_bl_|portable#
scrmbl~s_r___s|serious#
scrmbl~h__dph_n_|headphone#
```

Is it possible in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Find what: `[aeiou](?=.*\|)`

Replace with: `_`

Of course, you can choose if you want to add "y" to the regex.

Comment: Ah, my bad. It did work. I just had to uncheck . matches newline option. Thanks a lot.